# Is this variable not created on the heap?

Tags: c++, scope, stack, heap-memory

So, if I create a veriable using new, I understand I'm creating It on the heap right? And that It will exist till I call delete, so then why does this happen...?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    {
        int* a = new int;
        *a = 5;
    }
    std::cout << *a << std::endl; // error: 'a' was not declared in this scope
}
```

I mean, if I would've created `a` on the stack with `int a = 5;`, I would completely understand this error.

Comment: `a` is only visible within the scope braces (`{}`), the memory is allocated though, and leaked when that scope is left.

Comment: The memory is still there, what you have lost is the access to it as `int* a` is out of scope.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So then how would you solve that without wipping out the `{}`?

Comment: Have the `int* a` before the `{` and inside `a = new int` ?

Comment: Note that `new` does not necessarily imply a heap allocation. It can be optimized away. Live demo, kind-of similar to your case: https://godbolt.org/z/5oe1jK.

Comment: @Karlos Define the variable outside of the braces: `int* a = nullptr; { a = new int; *a = 5; }`

Comment: BTW, you basically have two variables (objects) here — the first one is a pointer `a` ("on the stack"), the second one is a dynamically created object of type `int` (created "on the heap"). You need to distinguish between both. `a` is not a dynamically created variable.

Comment: Typical newbie misunderstanding here. Variables are **never** created on the heap. The variable `a` is created on the stack. What the variable is pointing to is on the heap. but the variable and what it is pointing to are two different things. Until you understand this fundamental fact about pointers, they are always going to confuse you.

Comment: @john Then, why would I create something on the heap if I can't access It outside the scope where the pointer pointing to that variable is declared?

Comment: @Karlos You can (for instance) return the pointer from a function. That way the pointer is copied to another scope.

Comment: @Karlos `pointer pointing to that variable` is not correct terminology. The variable is the thing that has the scope. It is pointing at the heap memory which is anonymous, so doesn't have any scope. Pointers are **values**, not variables. When you say pointer variable, what's actually meant is a variable whose type allows it to hold pointer values. Such a variable is not fundamentally any different from a integer variable, which is just a variable whose type allows it to hold `int` values. Same rules about scope etc. apply to both types of variable.